# How can I change the background color of element in an array

Tags: javascript, html, random

I have an array of 5 divs

```
`<div id="cap-left2"</div>`
`<div id="cap-left1"</div>`
`<div id="cap-base"</div>`
`<div id="cap-right1"></div>`
`<div id="cap-right2"</div>`
```

all these divs have a background .
In my javascript I have :

```
let items = [capBase,capLeft1,capLeft2,capRight1,capRight2];
```

this works :

```
`var tom = items[Math.floor(Math.random()*items.length)]
console.log(tom)`
```

and this works

```
`var tom = items[Math.floor(Math.random()*items.length)]`
`console.log(tom.style)`
```

but I want the backgroundColor and neither of these work:

```
`var tom = items[Math.floor(Math.random()*items.length)]`
`console.log(tom.style.background)`


`var tom = items[Math.floor(Math.random()*items.length)]`
`console.log(tom.style.backgroundColor)`
```

what I am trying to do is lets say i have 5 swatches represented by 5 elements in an array . i want to be able to have a button that allows me to randomize what colors fill each element

any help would be appreciated

Comment: Missing > ?  Names in array don’t match html id’s?  tom.style seems wonky.

Comment: If you would put up a fiddle on this, I bet you'll have an answer in no time. :-)

Answer (score 1):

`element.style` represent style of the element, it will only be populated if `style` attribute is present (aka in-line style), CSS style will not affect that object.
So, `element.style.backgroundColor` will be empty, unless element has `style="background-color: red;"` as an attribute.
If you need get actual rendered style of an element, use
`window.getComputedStyle(element).backgroundColor`

```js
document.querySelectorAll("div").forEach( div =>
{
  console.log("style: " + div.style.backgroundColor, "final: " + window.getComputedStyle(div).backgroundColor, div);
});
```

```css
body > div[id]
{
  width: 1em;
  height: 1em;
  background-color: green;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<div id="cap-left2"></div>
<div id="cap-left1" style="background-color: red;"></div>
<div id="cap-base"></div>
<div id="cap-right1"></div>
<div id="cap-right2"></div>
```

Comment: sorry . i did not f5 the page and re answered the question that u already fixed it.

Answer (score 1):

```
const xx = window.getComputedStyle(searchBtn).getPropertyValue('background-color')
console.log(xx)
```

you can access only inline css proprty values via `style`property. You need `getComputedStyle`